# Passing more arguments to an onMessage function on a React component

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I have an `EventSource` that uses an `onMessage` function `loadGames` in `componentDidMount` of my `React` component, since the result is an array of objects i want to pass an argument to find an specific object from that array but i can't because when i define `onMessage` i do not call the function `loadGames` with any argument even though it has an `event` argument hidden inside

I have tried putting another function inside `componentDidMount` that uses that array but it can't because it executes all the functions before updating `mapStateToProps`

```
    //on my component file
   url = 'https://wheel-of-fortune-server.herokuapp.com'
   source = new EventSource(`${this.url}/stream`)

   componentDidMount() {
     this.source.onmessage=this.props.loadGames
     //if i write this.props.loadGames(event) i get a compilation error
   }

   //on my action file
  export function loadGames (event){
     //what i want to do is loadGames (event,gameId)
   const {data}=event
   const games=JSON.parse(data)
     //so i can do const game=games.find(game=>game.id===gameId)
   return {
      type: LOAD_ALL_GAMES,
      payload: games
   }
    }
```

Comment: You could make the onmessage handler a function that calls loadGames with the desired argument: `this.source.onmessage = event => this.props.loadGames(event);`.